# WCF/IIS 400 Error

Tags: c#, wcf, url, iis

I am getting a 400 error running my WCF service (.NET 3.5) in IIS7 with the following URL:

```
http://localhost/mrlabatch/MRLABatchProcessingService.svc/events/sr123%20eb/ACCESSCONTROL,ADT,ADTDERIVATION,ADTSTATIONNUMBER,ADTYEAR,CITY,COUNTY,FACILITYTYPE,FEDERALAIDROUTENUMBER,FUNCTIONALCLASSIFICATION,JURISDICTION,LEFTSHOULDERTYPE,LEFTSHOULDERWIDTH,LEFTSIDEWALKWIDTH,MASSDOTHIGHWAYDISTRICT,MEDIANTYPE,MEDIANWIDTH,MPO,NHSSTATUS,NUMBEROFPEAKHOURLANES,NUMBEROFTRAVELLANES,RIGHTOFWAYWIDTH,RIGHTSHOULDERTYPE,RIGHTSHOULDERWIDTH,RIGHTSIDEWALKWIDTH,ROUTEKEY,SPEEDLIMIT,STREETNAME,STREETOPERATION,SUBROUTE,SURFACETYPE,SURFACEWIDTH,TERRAIN,TRUCKROUTE,UNDIVIDEDLEFTSHOULDERTYPE,UNDIVIDEDLEFTSHOULDERWIDTH,URBANIZEDAREA,URBANTYPE/?frommp=8.28489&tomp=10.30031
```

The url will work fine in when debugging in Visual Studio (specifying a different port of course)

If I shorten the URL it works fine as well in both VS and IIS:

```
http://localhost/mrlabatch/MRLABatchProcessingService.svc/events/sr123%20eb/ACCESSCONTROL,ADT,ADTDERIVATION,ADTSTATIONNUMBER,ADTYEAR,CITY,COUNTY,FACILITYTYPE,FEDERALAIDROUTENUMBER,URBANIZEDAREA,URBANTYPE/?frommp=8.28489&tomp=10.30031
```

I've tried bumping my maxrequestlength up in the web.config:

Is there another obstruction to the URL size???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [this article](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits), it seems that if the URL was too long you would receive a 404 error, not a 400.  I would make sure that the requests are the same other than the url length.

You could check the IIS log on the server to make sure that the url (when it reaches the server) is what you are expecting.

It seems there might be a 260 character limit for urls in the .NET framework, but I would think that this would fail in the VS web server as well.

Comment: I saw that. It makes sense that it's not a url length issue. My solution was to actually add the query operator to the url "/EVENTS=ev1,ev2,ev3,ev4,...,evN"

Answer (score 1):

THe issue was with the URL I was posting. I should have added the proper query string into the URL:
    ?events=

```
 http://localhost/mrlabatch/MRLABatchProcessingService.svc/events/sr123%20eb/?events=ACCESSCONTROL,ADT,ADTDERIVATION,ADTSTATIONNUMBER,ADTYEAR,CITY,COUNTY,FACILITYTYPE,FEDERALAIDROUTENUMBER,FUNCTIONALCLASSIFICATION,JURISDICTION,LEFTSHOULDERTYPE,LEFTSHOULDERWIDTH,LEFTSIDEWALKWIDTH,MASSDOTHIGHWAYDISTRICT,MEDIANTYPE,MEDIANWIDTH,MPO,NHSSTATUS,NUMBEROFPEAKHOURLANES,NUMBEROFTRAVELLANES,RIGHTOFWAYWIDTH,RIGHTSHOULDERTYPE,RIGHTSHOULDERWIDTH,RIGHTSIDEWALKWIDTH,ROUTEKEY,SPEEDLIMIT,STREETNAME,STREETOPERATION,SUBROUTE,SURFACETYPE,SURFACEWIDTH,TERRAIN,TRUCKROUTE,UNDIVIDEDLEFTSHOULDERTYPE,UNDIVIDEDLEFTSHOULDERWIDTH,URBANIZEDAREA,URBANTYPE/?frommp=8.28489&tomp=10.30031
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm quite sure that your url is trimmed due to some invalid char or too long.

there are some limitation for url lenght.

try to use a POST instead of GET to pass so many stuff